# When replacing from "wcslen" to "strnlen_s", is it the correct way to typecast with "const char*"?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

When replacing from "wcslen" to "strnlen_s", is it the correct way to typecast with `const char*`?

In the below function I am replacing

`if (szPath[wcslen(szPath) - 1] != L'\\')`

with

`if (szPath[strnlen_s((const char*)szPath, sizeof(szPath)) - 1] != L'\\')`

Below is the code snippet:

```
bool Activation::Execute()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    typedef ULONG(APIENTRY *ActivateNowProc)(int);

    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];

    std::fill_n(szPath, MAX_PATH, L'\0');
    //Gets the  CSIDL Program files path
    hr = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, NULL, NULL, szPath);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        _tcscat_s(szPath, sizeof(szPath) / sizeof(TCHAR), MSC_PATH);
    }

    if (IsDirectoryExist(szPath))
    {
        std::wstringstream strActivationLibPath;
        strActivationLibPath << szPath;
        //if (szPath[wcslen(szPath) - 1] != L'\\') 
        if (szPath[strnlen_s((const char*)szPath, sizeof(szPath)) - 1] != L'\\')
            strActivationLibPath << L"\\";
        strActivationLibPath << OOBE_FOLDER_NAME << L"\\" << ACTIVATION_LIB_NAME;

        DWORD dwErr = McValidateModule(strActivationLibPath.str().c_str());
        if (dwErr != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(strActivationLibPath.str().c_str());
        if (hModule == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ActivateNowProc ActivateNow = (ActivateNowProc)GetProcAddress(hModule, ACTIVATION_PROC_NAME);
        if (ActivateNow)
        {
            long retVal = ActivateNow(1);
            if (retVal == E_FAIL)
            {
                FreeLibrary(hModule);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                ::Sleep(2000);
                CheckProcessRunningAndWait(SYNCPROCESSNAME);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FreeLibrary(hModule);
            return false;
        }
        FreeLibrary(hModule);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that using `strlen_s` on a non-`char` string is a good idea. IIRC `wchart_t` is a 16 bits character, you should use [wcsnlen_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strnlen-strnlen-s?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is definitely ***not*** the correct way!

Reason: Simply casting a `wchar_t` string pointer to a `char` pointer won't change the content of the string; as the 16-bit components of the wide string may possibly have elements whose 'upper byte' happens to be zero, then that would signal a premature end to the string. Also, even if this isn't the case, the value `strnlen_s` returns will be twice the value you want, as it will count each 16-bit `wchar_t` as two 8-bit `char` values.

Solution: As **Mathieu** has said, use `wcsnlen_s` instead! Always use the wcs... functions with `wchar_t` strings, and always use the str... functions for `char` strings.

EDIT: Also, I noticed in your code that you use `_tcscat_s`. Be careful when using the `_tcs…` functions on strings that aren't defined as `TCHAR` - because `TCHAR` evaluates to either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on what your compile/build settings are. So, add: … and always use _tcs… functions for `TCHAR` strings!

Comment: Or better yet just avoid the `@@_s()`-functions entirely.

Comment: @Deduplicator - The subject of whether or not to use MSVC's @@_s ('safe') versions of string functions is a whole new conversation in itself! They're a bit like Marmite.

Comment: @AdrianMole Only if you like to put hemlock and glass shards in your Marmite.